# Where can I find a full genealogy of human cell types?

Tags: cell-biology, development, differentiation

It is said on Wikipedia, that the precursor of [blastocyst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blastocyst) is a [morula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morula), and that the precursor of morula is a [zygote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygote). This gives us the part of genealogy tree of cell types. Unfortunately, no full genealogy can be found in Wikipedia.

Where can I find a more complete picture, preferably a full tree of cell types including information about each type?

Comment: I find it strange that this Q was downvoted, without any comment. The question is valid and interesting.

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia has a page listing cell types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distinct_cell_types_in_the_adult_human_body) which classifies their origin as endodermal or ectodermal.

I haven't been able to find a source for a complete lineage of all cell types, and I have gained the impression that there is no complete picture, except in some specific cases such as [the haemopoietic lineage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haematopoiesis).

[Here is a TEDX talk by a researcher in the field](http://www.tedxtelaviv.com/2010/07/18/ehud-shapiro-uncovering-the-human-cell-lineage-tree/), and [here is a slideshow](http://cordis.europa.eu/fp7/ict/fet-proactive/docs/flagship-ws-june10-18-ehud-shapiro_en.pdf) by the same person which lays out the problem and its importance.